# Trying to use $using in SetScript DSC Script Resource

Tags: powershell, resources, using, dsc

I am trying to use `$using` on my setscript for script resource and the script is failing to generate mof file.

My code:

```
Script Add_Admin_Account
        {
            GetScript = {
                            return $null;
                        }

            SetScript ={
                            $AdminGrp=[ADSI]"WinNT://localhost/Administrators,group";
                            $Usr=[ADSI]"WinNT://Domain\Username,User";
                            $using:AdminGrp.Add($using:Usr.Path)
                        }
            TestScript = {
                            $Check_User_Added = (net localgroup administrators | Select-String "Domain\Username" -SimpleMatch).ToString()
                            if ($Check_User_Added) 
                            {
                            Write-Verbose "User $Check_User_Added is part of Admin Group";
                            return $true; } 
                            else { return $false; }

                        }
        }
```

If I try to use only this `$using:AdminGrp.Add` the mof gets created but it is of no use when trying to run `Start-DScConfiguration`.

Also, if I try to use 
Line1 : $using:AdminGrp.Add
Line2: ($using:Usr.Path)
 the mof gets created but it has `\n` for new line.

When I use `$using:AdminGrp.Add($using:Usr.Path)` or `$using:AdminGrp.Add()` or `$using:AdminGrp.Add(` it fails on to generate the mof.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Found the problem and fixed the script. Issue was on the TestScript and SetScript.

TestScript:
$usrname=$using:Node.Add_Admin_Group_Name
$Check_User_Added = (net localgroup administrators | Select-String $usrname -SimpleMatch)
if ($Check_User_Added -Like $usrname) 
{ Write-Verbose "User $usrname is part of Admin Group"; 
return $true; }  else  { Write-Verbose "User $usrname is NOT part of Admin Group"; return $false; }

SetScript:
$usrname=$using:Node.Add_Admin_Group_Name                ([ADSI]"WinNT://./Administrators,group").Add("WinNT://$usrname")